# bash scripting - trouble renaming files in subdirectories using find / rename

Tags: bash

I have a large series of directories and subdirectories with many jpgs in them. I need to do two things:

1. Create a copy of each jpg found within it's own subdirectory
2. Rename this copied jpg such that apple.jpg becomes apple_m.jpg

I have tried to run the following commands in order:

//this creates a copy of every jpg found and appends '_m' to the end of it

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -execdir cp {} {}_m \;
```

//now again find everything with 'jpg_m' at the end and rename it as filename_m.jpg

```
find . -name '*.jpg_m' -execdir rename -v 's/\.jpg_m/_m\.jpg/' {} \;
```

However the 2nd command does'nt seem to work, can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Adi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename files, you can simply use it this way
`rename ".jpg_m" "_m.jpg" files_to_rename`

so, if you want to copy and rename, you can rename it this way:

```
find . -name "*.jpg_m" -execdir rename ".jpg_m" "_m.jpg" {} \;
```

Comment: You can even use `\+` instead of `\;` to pass multiple filenames to `rename` at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in one pass?

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec cp {} m_{} \; -exec rename "m_" "" {} \;
```

Comment: I need it to work with subfolders so tried changing your solution to use 'execdir' instead of exec but it still does'nt work, also need to put in "m_" at the end or this happens: cp: cannot create regular file `m_./groupThumb70X70.jpg': No such file or directory